# Errors while encoding data sequentially with Scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am looping through the rows of my data frame and I am trying to encode each row of data using my encoder.

```
for index, row in self.data.iterrows():
    data = self._encoder.transform(row)
    try:
        print(row.shape)
        results["classes"].append((self._model.predict(data) > 0.5).astype("int32"))
        results["probability"].append((self._model.predict(data)))
        results["rows"].append(index)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        results["rows"].append(index)
        results["classes"].append("ERROR")
        results["probability"].append("ERROR")
```

And then predict using my model. Both the encoder and the model were made with Scikit-learn and Keras, the model was saved using the built in save function of keras and the encoder was exported to a joblib file. If I encode the whole data frame everything works as expected.

I am trying to do this sequentially to avoid potential breakdowns of my program when the encoder throws an error about the data, specifically when a new value appears in one of the columns that I am one hot encoding, a value that the encoder has not seen before.

I have tried using `iterrows()`, and when I try to encode each row I get the following error.
`IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

I have also tried to transform each row into a data frame of its own but i get the following when I try to encode `ValueError: Number of features of the input must be equal to or greater than that of the fitted transformer. Transformer n_features is 67 and input n_features is 1.`

What would be the best approach to loop through my data and encode and predict sequentially each row of data?

Complete trace of the second error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/build/x-predictive-model/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    network.predictSequentially()
  File "/home/build/x-predictive-model/myai.py", line 191, in predictSequentially
    encoded = self._encoded_data = self._encoder.transform(pd.DataFrame(row))
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/x-model-lib/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 571, in transform
    .format(self._n_features, X.shape[1]))
ValueError: Number of features of the input must be equal to or greater than that of the fitted transformer. Transformer n_features is 67 and input n_features is 1.
```

Comment: Please format your code either with inverse quotes or with indentation, but not with both (edited).

Comment: Can you add the shapes of your data and the full traceback of the second error?

Comment: @ML_Engine the shape of the data is (4722, 67), I have posted the full traceback in the body of the post

Answer (score 0):

Can loop and predict by using the index, using the syntax `self.data[index:index+1]` I can loop trough my data and make predictions.